# Python 3 clear list/restart if total > a set number but it keeps going

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

*Warning*: I am new to Python.  This code WILL be primitive.

I am appending random numbers into a list until I get to "4".

When adding elements of list...
1. If I get 10, break while loop and print list.
2. If I get <10, resume.
3. If I get > 10, clear list and resume.

So far, the first 2 work. But when it is >4, it just keeps going.

I tried this just using variables and not a list but I had problems with global vs local values.

```
import random
import time

totalNums = []
count = 1
while count > 0:
    rndNum = random.randint(3, 5)
    totalNums.append(rndNum)
    overLoadCheck = sum(list(totalNums))
    print ("Operation #:", count, "Current Num:", rndNum, "Total Nums:", overLoadCheck)
    time.sleep(1)
    if overLoadCheck > 10:
        totalNums.clear
    elif overLoadCheck == 10:
        break
    count = count + 1

print (totalNums)
```

Comment: Probably you need `totalNums.clear()`